# Are the minhagim during sefira binding?

Tags: halacha, minhag

It is clear that we are not obligated to follow the Minhag hamukem if the minhag has no halachic basis. For example if my Bubbe ate chicken soup on Shabbos that is not binding upon me, since it has no Halachic basis.

The way i see it, the minhagim of sefira have no halachic basis either. It is not mentioned in the Talmud (though the story is mentioned) and something that is not mentioned in the Talmud can never become part of Halacha binding upon all Jews. Furthermore there's no Halacha that a Jew is commanded to mourn the death of Torah scholars. Can we say that these minhagim are not binding but optional?

On the other hand, the Tur and Shulchan did incorporate them into their Halachic code (though the rambam did not). This would seem to suggest that they are binding upon all!

P.s. This question can also be viewed as a general question as to what makes a minhag binding.

Comment: why because the Tur and Shulchan Aruch incorporated them does it make them binding?

Comment: There actually is a halakha that a Jew is obligated to mourn the death of Torah scholars (YD 374:10).

Comment: "P.s. This question can also be viewed as a general question as to what makes a minhag binding." Then consider just asking that, (itself a fundamental question) so that you don't get bogged down with the details of sefira. After you get some nice answers, you will likely know the answer to sefira, or at least the relevant variables which you can then ask about separately.

Comment: I don't get the question. The Tur (it goes earlier (including the Ritz Gayes, a Rishon from before the Rambam), but whatever), Shulchan Aruch, and later consider it a binding custom. Just because there wasn't such a custom in the Gemara's time and the Rambam doesn't mention it, doesn't make it invalid.

Comment: By the way, while something not mentioned in the Talmud can't become binding on "all Jews", it can become binding on "some Jews". So unless you come from a community that didn't accept this custom, it still may be binding.

Comment: @DoubleAA do u think this is a duplicate?

Comment: The last line summarises the question as: "This question can also be viewed as a general question as to what makes a minhag binding". which seems equivalent to the "what determines a minhag question".

Comment: no its not equivalent to that. that is about how you start a minhag, and this is about what makes a minhag obligatory! Now how do i get rid of this duplicate marking?

Comment: What's a non-obligatory minhag? What's a "halachic basis"?

Comment: @Bach Meh I'm not convinced it is a duplicate but that's mostly because I don't really understand the post.